# Why does a quantum wave function reflect even when E > V?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential-energy

I'm thinking about the quantum case of a particle of energy E coming in from the left and encountering a step potential:

[image]

As I understand, some of the wave function will reflect from the step whether E > V0 or E < V0. In the latter case, this is easy to understand from a classical perspective.

Is there any good way to think about why some of the wave function is reflected by the step barrier, even when E > V0?

Comment: How about some light reflecting from the interface with a transparent medium?